# How to attach two or multiple files and send mail in PHP

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments

The code below sends only one attachment, but I need to attach and send two file(one rar file and pdf)

```
$email_to = "$email"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from = "online@example.co.in"; // The email you are sending from (example)
$email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
$fileatt = "files/example.rar"; // Path to the file (example)
$fileatt_type = "application/x-rar-compressed"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = "example.rar"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers="From: $email_from"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

Comment: use phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: You really shouldn't be using php's mail() function for this.

Answer (score 18):

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
 <input type="file" name="csv_file[]" />
 <br/>

 <input type="file" name="csv_file[]" />
 <br/>

 <input type="file" name="csv_file[]" />
 <br/>

 <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
 <br/>

</form> 

<?php

if($_POST) {

    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['csv_file']['name']); $i++){

        $ftype[]       = $_FILES['csv_file']['type'][$i];
        $fname[]       = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'][$i];

    }


    // array with filenames to be sent as attachment
    $files = $fname;

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "example@gmail.com";
    $from = "example@gmail.com"; 
    $subject ="My subject"; 
    $message = "My message";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    // send

    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) { 
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
    } 



}

?>
```

Comment: awesome... working perfectly :)

Comment: Its worked for me also, Great Help :)

Comment: Thank you, worked for me also.

Comment: That's awful code, which has multiple issues (dated for loop, not using file_get_contents, missing CRLF, wrongly wrapped content type, missing length fields). Manual MIME multipart payload construction copypasta is not worth fixing or basing new questions on (attachments don't open etc.)

Answer (score 11):

Following the [reusability principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reusability), you can use https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name                               

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Answer (score 9):

Check the following Multiple file attachment in core php mail function.

```
<?php
/** Mail with attachment */
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $bcc, $subject, $message){    
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$uid}x"; 

    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= nl2br($message)."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

    foreach($filename as $k=>$v){

        $file = $path.$v;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$v."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$v."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."--"."\r\n";
    } 

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        //echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        return true;
    } else {
        //echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the best solution i got for multiple mail attachment and tested successfully.

This code gives you freedom by attaching file in email without uploading in your hosting server space. Which is highly needed.

There are many solution telling how to upload files to your server and then send to email, but this solution gives "*Direct multiple file attachment to email*"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>E-mail with Attachment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

   // we'll begin by assigning the To address and message subject
   $to="me@me.com";
   $subject="E-mail with attachment";

   // get the sender's name and email address
   // we'll just plug them a variable to be used later
   $from = stripslashes($_POST['fromname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['fromemail']).">";

   // generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

   // now we'll build the message headers
   $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

   // here, we'll start the message body.
   // this is the text that will be displayed
   // in the e-mail
   $message="This is an example";

   $message .= "Name:".$_POST["fromname"]."Message Posted:".$_POST["modlist"];

   // next, we'll build the invisible portion of the message body
   // note that we insert two dashes in front of the MIME boundary 
   // when we use it
   $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
   $message . "\n\n";

   // now we'll process our uploaded files
   foreach($_FILES as $userfile){
      // store the file information to variables for easier access
      $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
      $type = $userfile['type'];
      $name = $userfile['name'];
      $size = $userfile['size'];

      // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
      if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

         // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
         if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

            // open the file for a binary read
            $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

            // read the file content into a variable
            $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

            // close the file
            fclose($file);

            // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
         }

         // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
         // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
         // an attachment, then add the file content.
         // NOTE: we don't set another boundary to indicate that the end of the 
         // file has been reached here. we only want one boundary between each file
         // we'll add the final one after the loop finishes.
         $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
            " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
            " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n";
      }
   }
   // here's our closing mime boundary that indicates the last of the message
   $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
   // now we just send the message
   if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
      echo "Message Sent";
   else
      echo "Failed to send";
} else {
?>
<p>Send an e-mail with an attachment:</p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
   <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="fromname"></p>
   <p>Your e-mail: <input type="text" name="fromemail"></p>
   <p>Mod List: <textarea  name="question" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" name="modlist"></textarea>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file1"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file2"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file3"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file4"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file5"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file6"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file7"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file8"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You nailed it. It works like a charm. A million blessings to you Guru and Hein Pauwelyn.

Comment: This worked great...except you forgot one important item, the mime boundary terminator.  $uid      = md5(time()); 
 $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$uid}x";

and after all the attachments are associated, completing the message with:
 $message .= "--".$uid."--";

Answer (score 1):

Simple working and tested example:

```
<?php
  mail_attachment("mail@mail.com","Subject","Here is the body",array("file1.pdf","file2.pdf"));
  function mail_attachment($to, $subject, $message, $files) {
      $headers = "From: no-reply@mail.com";
      $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

      foreach ($files as $file) {

        $filename = end(explode("/",$file));  
        $data = file_get_contents($file);

        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      }
        echo (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? "<p>Send to $to!</p>" : "<p>Not send toaar $to!</p>"; 
  } // mail-attachment
?>
```

Comment: The only change that is required to comply with newer PHP versions is to break `$filename = end(explode("/",$file));` into `$tmp = explode("/", $file); $filename = end($tmp);` as it will throw an "Only variables should be passed by reference" error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Put your files in an array, then using a form loop add each of them in the `$email_message` variable

```
$email_to = "$email"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from = "online@example.co.in"; // The email you are sending from (example)
$email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
$email_message = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
$files = array("file_1.ext","file_2.ext","file_3.ext",......);
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers="From: $email_from"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $email_message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

Hope it works fine :)

Comment: kakashihatake2 its not working

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: @mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using to send multiple attachments, I hope this helps you too. You actually need to use a loop at attach multiple files.

```
    $files = array("file1.pdf","file2.pdf");
    $body = "email in html form";

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "e-mail id of person you are sending to";
    $from = "your e-mail id";
    $subject = "email subject";
    $message = html_entity_decode($body);
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

   // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"   {$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++) {
        $file = fopen($files[$x], "rb");
        $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    // send

    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($ok) {
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple> //select multiple file
$target_dir = "upload/"; //first upload your directory path
$names =  $_FILES['file']['name'];   //file Name
$i =0;
foreach($names as $name){
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($name); //first upload your     
directory path
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file);  
//upload your directory         
$mail->addAttachment($target_file); //after upload file path 
fetch and   atachment
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please enhance your answer with a little information. Why does this work, what did the original asker wrong?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this line from the original post, as well as some of the answers, will cause a problem on some email systems.

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .

The \n at the beginning caused the attachments to fail when sending to an address hosted at emailpros.com, a secure HIPAA compliant email system.  Simply removing the line break fixed the issue there.  However, it had been working just fine when sending to a Gmail account and another host (Hostmonster).
This way worked just fine on all of them.
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
// upload recommendation file section
$target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/rec_file/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["RC_file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["RC_file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $error_msg = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $error_msg = "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["RC_file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $error_msg = "your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["RC_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["RC_file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. ". $error_msg ;
    }
}

// upload driven licence file section

$DL_target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/rec_file/";
$DL_target_file = $DL_target_dir . basename($_FILES["DL_file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($DL_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["DL_file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $error_msg = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $error_msg = "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($DL_target_file)) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["DL_file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $error_msg = "your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["DL_file"]["tmp_name"], $DL_target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["DL_file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. ". $error_msg ;
    }
}

    // array with filenames to be sent as attachment

    $files = array($target_file,$DL_target_file);

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "tkdilankumara@gmail.com";
    $from = "help@soosti.com"; 
    $subject ="Member Registration"; 
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $eol = "\r\n";

    $message .= "Member Registration Information.".$eol;
    $message .= $username.$eol;
    $message .= $email.$eol;
    $message .= $Fname.$eol;
    $message .= $Lname.$eol;
    $message .= $address.$eol;


        // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

        // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        //$file = @fopen($files[$x],"rb");
        //$data = @fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
        //@fclose($file);
        $content =file_get_contents($files[$x],"rb");
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $content . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
}
?>
```