# PHPMailer send multiple attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer

HI im trying to send multiple attachment with php mailer but only one attachment being sent even both files are uploaded and path are correct below is code. in second iteration `$mail->addAttachment` return false.

```
if  (is_array( $email_attachment )) {

    foreach ($email_attachment as $attachment ) {

        $mail->addAttachment($attachment ); 

        var_dump($attachment);
        echo '<br/>';  

        var_dump($mail->addAttachment($attachment));
        echo '<br/>'; 
    }

     die();
}
```

dump result.

```
string(62) "D:\htdocs\express-english/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/23882.jpg" 
bool(true) 
string(63) " D:\htdocs\express-english/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/97778.jpg" 
bool(false)
```

Comment: this is not seems correct "D:\htdocs\express-english/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/23882.jpg"  check attachment url:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296406/4248328  . you can check your code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd string contains a space in front of it

```
string(63) " D:\htdocs\express-english/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/97778.jpg"
```

you should trim that with

```
$attachment = trim($attachment);
```

before using `$mail->addAttachment`

Comment: yes there is space being added in my code did not notice working now. Thanks.