# How to attach 2 different images in mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) && $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] ==  UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);}
```

this is the code im using for uploading the first image, this code is working and im getting the attachment in main but how to do it for second image.

Comment: I assume you are using a mail library of some sort! Can you tell us which one, it may well be relevant

Comment: Im using php mailer

Comment: There is a TAG for that, and using it will attract those people that know that library

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you are using PHPMailer so you can do it like this:

```
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);}

 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file2']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file2']['name']);}
```

you can follow this sample:
[How to send multiple attachment in single mail in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296361/how-to-send-multiple-attachment-in-single-mail-in-php)

Comment: STILL ONLY ONE IMAGE GOES TO MAIL ATTACHMENT

Comment: first of all, turn off the caps lock, looks like you are screaming. Post the complete code

Comment: hahaha im not screamiing i removed the attachment code form if statement now its working 
Thanks!!!