# How to attach multiple files in mail using php?

Tags: php, html, css, database

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);  

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'reflexivezhcet@gmail.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

This code is for sending only text to the recipient how could I improve it for sending multiple files using php? Is there any need for maintaining database for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245082/how-to-attach-two-or-multiple-files-and-send-mail-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function to send multi email attachment:

```
function multi_attach_mail($to, $subject, $message, $senderMail, $senderName, $files){

    $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">"; 
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

    // preparing attachments
    if(count($files) > 0){
        for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp =    @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
                $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));

                @fclose($fp);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" . 
                "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" . 
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

    //send email
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath); 

    //function return true, if email sent, otherwise return fasle
    if($mail){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }

}

//email variables
$to = 'receiver email id';
$from = 'info@codexworld.com';
$from_name = 'CodexWorld';

//attachment files path array
$files = array('path/to/file1.etx', 'path/to/file2.etx');
$subject = 'PHP Email with multiple attachments by CodexWorld'; 
$html_content = '<h1>PHP Email with multiple attachments by CodexWorld</h1>
            <p><b>Total Attachments : </b>'.count($files).' attachments</p>';

//call multi_attach_mail() function and pass the required arguments
$send_email = multi_attach_mail($to,$subject,$html_content,$from,$from_name,$files);

//print message after email sent
echo $send_email?"<h1> Mail Sent</h1>":"<h1> Mail not SEND</h1>";
```

Source is [here](http://www.codexworld.com/send-html-email-multiple-attachments-php/)

Comment: @rahul If you are aware that your language is questionable, then please change it.

Comment: So you think it is not questionable, but you do ask for pardon because of it? What is it about your language that needs a pardon? Maybe your choice of expressions? That seems the most obvious reason to ask for pardon. Please elaborate.