# Sending multiple attachments PHP imap only sending 1 attachment

Tags: php, imap

script works but only sends one attachment. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. It will send the first attachment $userfile['name'][0], but not $userfile['name'][1]

```
   $i = 0;
   foreach($_FILES as $userfile){
      $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'][$i];
      $type = $userfile['type'][$i];
      $name = $userfile['name'][$i];
      $size = $userfile['size'][$i];
          $i++;
}

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
 <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
```

original code is from here: [How to attach two or multiple files and send mail in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245082/how-to-attach-two-or-multiple-files-and-send-mail-in-php/34745541#34745541)

Comment: this is not the attachment sending code. Please provide full code if you want any useful help

Comment: You're just trying to get the files the wrong way. See my answer. You shouldl specify the file array name in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your filename to userfile[], then should be like this:

Should be like this:

```
$count_uploaded_files = count( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );

for( $i = 0; $i < $count_uploaded_files; $i++ )
{
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $type     = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $name     = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $size     = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

    // Do whatever you want with $temp_name, $type, $name, and $size ...
}
```

But if you want to stay with file[]. then like this:

```
$count_uploaded_files = count( $_FILES['file']['name'] );

for( $i = 0; $i < $count_uploaded_files; $i++ )
{
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $type     = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
    $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $size     = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

    // Do whatever you want with $temp_name, $type, $name, and $size ...
}
```

Comment: Second option works. Thanks.