# Send mail with multiple PDF files php

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send more than one pdf and I didn't found any that works for me. 
I tried this [How to attach two or multiple files and send mail in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245082/how-to-attach-two-or-multiple-files-and-send-mail-in-php)

My problem is that only one pdf is attached. Here is my code.

```
public function sendMultiple($from,$to,$subject,$files){
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $separator = md5(time());

    $headers  = "From: \"".$from."\" <".$this->replyTo.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;

    $body = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $this->getMessage().$eol;
    foreach ($files as $file ) {
        $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file['name'] . "\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $file['file'] . $eol;
        $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
    }
    $mail = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    if($mail){
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}

//$files is an array of this
$file1 = array("name"=>"name".$name1.".pdf","file"=>chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf)));
$file2 = array("name"=>"name".$name2.".pdf","file"=>chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf2)));
array_push($files, $file1);
array_push($files, $file2);
```

Comment: Try to add `. $eol` to last line in the `foreach`

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the response, I tested with that and the email is not being sent, no errors, mail is not appearing. I'm using Gmail

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, here is the code:

```
public function sendMultiple($from,$to,$subject,$files){
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $separator = md5(time());

    $headers  = "From: \"".$from."\" <".$this->replyTo.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;

    $body = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $this->getMessage().$eol;
    foreach ($files as $file ) {
        $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file['name'] . "\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $file['file'] . $eol;
        //This line is not needed, solved the issue
        //$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
    }
    $mail = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    if($mail){
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}

//$files is an array of this
$file1 = array("name"=>"name".$name1.".pdf","file"=>chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf)));
$file2 = array("name"=>"name".$name2.".pdf","file"=>chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf2)));
array_push($files, $file1);
array_push($files, $file2);
```